# Merging 2 ddrescue output of the same drive efficiently

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, file-transfer, ddrescue

I am trying to rescue a partition in a failing 500GB hard drive at `/dev/sdb` using ddrescue to a second 1TB drive. The ddrescue command I use for first pass is:

```
ddrescue -n /dev/sdb2 core.img core.log
```

followed by second pass:

```
ddrescue -d -r 3 /dev/sdb2 core.img core.log
```

The problem is, I accidentally mistype the image name for the second command. Instead of `core.img`, I write `core.ing` and I did not realize it until the next morning where the second pass has run its course, and core.log overwritten to report a 100% success.

Now I am stuck with 2 massive files. Re-running the entire chore is not feasible as I am still rescuing `sdb3`. I already checked with `hexedit` and the 2 file compliments each other (i.e. if in offset 0x5000 to 0x7000 `core.img` is filled with zero, then the same offset in `core.ing` is filled with the real data, vice versa.)

I am thinking of `dd`-ing the `core.img` to `/dev/sdc2` (the replacement drive for `sdb` I prepared) and then somehow copy *only* the non-zero bytes in `core.ing` to `/dev/sdc2` but I am not sure how can I only copy the nonzero bytes, and using what, as the solutions I can think of are very cumbersome and will take forever to complete.

For reference, I am running Gentoo-based SystemRescueCD 4.9.6, `sdb2` is NTFS.

Comment: Hi Dariel; I see you've also [posted this to the Unix and Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359454/merging-2-ddrescue-output-of-the-same-drive-efficiently); this [isn't permitted as per the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). The question itself is fine, but it should really only be on one or the other. As the FFAQ answer says, if you don't get a response and you feel another site would be a better fit, you can ask a mod to migrate the question. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for notifying me, I cross-posted because I think this question fits better in SU site. I'll delete the one on the Unix & Linux site to comply with the rules

Comment: No problem, if that's your choice it's worth an upvote as it's a well-phrased question (as it's at +3 on U&L it's been well-received; but didn't +1 beforehand as it felt disingenuous to upvote something against the rules). It is on-topic on either so the choice is yours :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How can I merge two different rescues?

*(This assumes GNU `ddrescue`)*

**tl;dr**:

1. Generate a mapfile/logfile for the first copy: `ddrescue --generate-mode infile outfile mapfile`
2. Create a merged copy from 2nd → 1st [as described in a post to the `ddrescue` mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2011-12/msg00020.html): `ddrescue -m logfile2 image2 image1 logfile1`

---

### 1. Generate a log file for the first image

This is slightly complicated as you effectively don't have a log file for the first pass. However, you can generate one:

> When ddrescue is invoked with the `--generate-mode` option it operates in "generate mode", which is different from the default "rescue mode". That is, if you use the '--generate-mode' option, ddrescue does not rescue anything. It only tries to generate a mapfile for later use.
>
> ...
>
> Don't despair (yet). Ddrescue can in some cases generate an approximate mapfile, from infile and the (partial) copy in outfile, that is almost as good as an exact mapfile. It makes this by simply assuming that **sectors containing all zeros were not rescued**.
>
> ... you can generate an approximate mapfile with this command:
>
> `ddrescue --generate-mode infile outfile mapfile`

*(emphasis mine)*

from the [GNU `ddrescue` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Generate-mode); section 12, '**Generate mode**'.

So you can do this for the first image (which I suggest renaming to avoid confusion, eg `core-1.img`):

```
ddrescue -G /dev/sdb2 core-1.img core-1.log
```

#### "I'm still reading from `/dev/sdb`, will generating a log interefere with that?"

Note that `ddrescue` reconstructs from the `outfile` (in this case, `core-1.img`) primarily, with very few reads from `infile`. I tested this with `inotifywatch`:

```
$ inotifywatch 840-linux.img # infile
$ inotifywatch 840-linux2.img # outfile
$ inotifywatch 840-linux2.log
$ ddrescue -G 840-linux.img 840-linux2.img 840-linux2.log

total  close_nowrite  open  filename
6      3              3     840-linux.img
17467  17465   1              1     840-linux2.img

total  access  modify  close_write  close_nowrite  open  filename
196    1       189     2            1              3     840-linux2.log
```

So it is safe to run this while another process is running on `sdb` (in OP's case, [another rescue attempt on a different partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1200471/merging-2-ddrescue-output-of-the-same-drive-efficiently/1200483?noredirect=1#comment1746415_1200483)) as the reads are negligible.

### 2. Merge the two partial copies

This sort of situation [has cropped up before](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2011-12/msg00018.html):

> So now I have two partial images of the drive that mostly don't overlap... and two matching log files to go with them that define the good areas and slow areas skipped.

Fortunately, they can be merged using [`--domain-mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#g_t_002d_002ddomain_002dmapfile):

> ```
> --domain-mapfile=file
>    Restrict the rescue domain to the blocks marked as 
>    finished in the mapfile file. This is useful for 
>    merging partially recovered images of backups, or if 
>    the destination drive fails during the rescue. Use 
>    '-' as file to read from standard in`
> ```

And [the solution to the similar problem involved that option](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2011-12/msg00020.html):

> you can merge the images by typing:
>
> ```
> cd dir1
> ddrescue -m dir2/logfile dir2/image image logfile
> ```
>
> This creates the files dir1/logfile dir1/image with all the data currently rescued. Then you can continue the rescue for example like this:

In your case, assuming you have generated a log file for `core.img` and labelled them `1`, and kept the `core.ing` and `core.log` as `2` (lest there be more confusion!):

```
ddrescue -m core-2.log core-2.img core-1.img core-1.log
```

Comment: Speaking of confusion, this question was [cross posted to U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359454/merging-2-ddrescue-output-of-the-same-drive-efficiently/359485#359485), I have copied my answer from there in case of deletion. See [this part of chat for ref](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36759388#36759388). I am happy to remove this answer if cross-answering falls afoul of any guidelines!

Comment: Thanks, a question though, will the `-G` option cause ddrescue to read from `/dev/sdb2` again? As I am currently recovering another partition of the same drive. And I have requested the one I post to the Unix&Linux to be deleted as I think this question fits better to this site.

Comment: It *shouldn't*, as it's just reading from `outfile` to generate the `mapfile`; I presume the use of `infile` is for consistency/verifying the image makes sense for the `outfile`. However I haven't tested this; I can try it on an image file I have and see. **Update**: AFAICT it seems to generate from `outfile` alone.

Comment: I have updated the answer with that `inotify` information.

Comment: Thanks for the updated info and answer! The methods you specify should definitely work, so I'll be marking your answer as solution

Comment: Hmm, after I re-created the core-1.log I noticed that I will need to re-create core-2.log too with `ddrescue -G /dev/sdb2 core-2.img core-2.log` so that the last command can work, Am I correct?

Comment: So yes I also regenerate core-2.log and use then `ddrescue -C -m core-2.log core-2.img core-1.img core-1.log` (The -C being necessary as core-2.img is smaller than core-1.img due to omitted zeroes at the trailing end) The core-1.img is now the complete image, and all is well (you might want to edit your answer to include the core-2.log regeneration for future readers). Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it's sorted :) I actually intended for you to use the `core.log` from the *second* run as `core-2.log`, sorry for being unclear- regenerating it works as well though!